# html tables. Sync column spacing between 2 tables;

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have 2 tables in separate `<div>`'s. One is the header and the other is the actual data which is scrollable. The issue is that they don't line up. I'm using jQuery and the tables are in a re-sizable area so i don't want to set static column widths. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to put them in one parent container?

Then try to set the width of both tables to 100% (or another similar value).

Comment: they are in a parent <div> and the width is set to 100%. But they still don't line up.